# Running Shell script written in linux on windows OS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, cygwin

i have shell script written in RedHat OS. I need to run this script in windows environemtn.

So i used cygwin to run the script on windows.

But when i run the script using

```
sh housekeeper.sh
```

it gives me following error which is not retured in RedHat OS

```
line 12: $'\r': command not found
```

but line number 12 of my script is empty

```
  08  #
  09  ######################################################################
  10  #### PARAMETERS TO SET BEGIN
  11  ######################################################################
  12  
  13  # archive setttings
  14  ARCHIVE_USER=abc                      # archive storage user name  (default)
  15  ARCHIVE_GROUP=app                     # archive storage user group (default)
  16  ARCHIVE_PATH=/test/file               # archive storage directory (default)
  17  ARCHIVE_DELAY=+8
```

could anybody tell me whats wrong with the script here or cygwin here.

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely cygwin `sh` is expecting a UNIX line separator (i.e. `\n`) but is instead finding a Windows line separator, `\r\n`, and hence is trying to execute `\r` as if it were a command. This could easily have happened if you edited this script in a Windows-based text editor.

If you have the command `dos2unix` you could use that, or `tr` to remove `\r`s:

```
tr -d '\r' < old.sh > new.sh
```

Comment: In the event that there is a significant carriage return somewhere in the script, this is safer than tr: `sed 's/\r$//'`

Answer (score 1):

Run `dos2unix` command on Windows on this file and then try running this

Comment: `dos2unix` is the command that would be needed - not `unix2dos`.